# I am getting an error when I try to extract all the urls of this website. What can I do?

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape URLs, But I get an error the `label empty or too long`. The error happens in *middle* of scraping the URLs

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin, quote

def scrape(site):
    visited = set()
    queue = [site]

    while queue:
        current_url = queue.pop(0)
        if current_url in visited:
            continue

        visited.add(current_url)

        try:
            r = requests.get(current_url, timeout=5)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to {current_url}: {e}")
            continue

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.find_all("a"):
            href = link.get("href")
            if href is not None:
                full_url = urljoin(site, quote(href, safe='/:?=&'))
                if site in full_url and full_url not in visited:
                    queue.append(full_url)
                    print(full_url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    site = "http://www.nuigalway.ie"
    scrape(site)
```

However, I get an erorr:

```
Getting this error - 
    hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(hostonly)
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

How can I scrape all urls of the website?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and I found that there's a link causing the problem is: `http://www.universityofgalway.ie/sustainability/` with `http`. however, its should really be `https`.

So, you can simply use Try/Except to see if there's a `UnicodeError` and then replace the URL with an `https` (the added **s**)

```py
visited.add(current_url)

try:
    r = requests.get(current_url, timeout=5)
except UnicodeError:
    r = requests.get(current_url.replace('http', 'https'), timeout=5)
...
```